# Why is there a discontinuity at zero?

Tags: graphing-functions

For the function
$$y = \frac{2x^2}{x-3},$$
I understand that $x = 3$ and $y = 2x+6$ are asymptote, but according to the answers in my textbook, there is a discontinuity at the origin. Why is this?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: Discontinuit fot the function at the origin? Your book is wrong!

Comment: The book is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For, discontinuity at $x=0$, let's check both left hand & right hand limits as follows

$$LHL=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{2x^2}{x-3}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(0-h)^2}{(0-h)-3}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2h^2}{-h-3}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-2h^2}{h+3}=\frac{-2(0)^2}{0+3}=0$$

Similarly, $$RHL=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{2x^2}{x-3}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(0+h)^2}{(0+h)-3}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2h^2}{h-3}$$ $$=\frac{2(0)^2}{0+3}=0$$  & we have $$f(0)=\frac{2(0)^2}{0-3}=0$$ Thus, we have $$LHL=RHL=f(0)$$ Hence the function $y=\frac{2x^2}{x-3}$ is continuous at $x=0$ i.e. it has no discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: Very-very long and sound for such trivial problem.

Comment: But for proving continuity or discontinuity at $x=a$, we have to prove $LHL=RHL=f(a)$ . Isn't it right?

Comment: Great thank you! So it must have been wrong in the textbook.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Yes, this is rather like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer. But when the "fly" is a statement made with the authority of a textbook, it becomes a big, big, hairy fly, and to make sure you really kill it, the sledgehammer may be a good tool.

Comment: @DavidK, textbook is not Pope

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Of course no textbook is the Pope, but from the point of view of a student, when the student's understanding contradicts the book, the error is almost always on the student's side. At first glance, then, "the book is wrong" is an extraordinary claim for the student to believe, and so extraordinary evidence is merited.

Answer (score 2):

There is no discontinuity at the origin.